# How do you put an image file in a json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I am making a database for video games, each containing elements like name, genre, and and image of the game. Is it possible to put images into a json object for the db?  If not is there a way around this?

Comment: you can [convert it to base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @WhiteHat how does base 64 work?

Comment: just means, convert the image to a `base64` string, which can be converted back to an image --> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22172860/5090771)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store images in a mongo database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongo-database)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I can think of doing it in two ways:

### 1.

Storing the file in file system in any directory (say `dir1`) and renaming it which ensures that the name is unique for every file (may be a timestamp) (say `xyz123.jpg`), and then storing this name in some DataBase. Then while generating the JSON you pull this filename and generate a complete URL (which will be `http://example.com/dir1/xyz123.png` )and insert it in the JSON.

### 2.

Base 64 Encoding, It's basically a way of encoding arbitrary binary data in ASCII text. It takes 4 characters per 3 bytes of data, plus potentially a bit of padding at the end. Essentially each 6 bits of the input is encoded in a 64-character alphabet. The "standard" alphabet uses A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and + and /, with = as a padding character. There are URL-safe variants. So this approach will allow you to put your image directly in the MongoDB, while storing it Encode the image and decode while fetching it, it has some of its own drawbacks:

- base64 encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger than their original binary representations, which means more data down the wire (this might be exceptionally painful on mobile networks)
- data URIs aren’t supported on IE6 or IE7.
- base64 encoded data may possibly take longer to process than binary data.

[Source](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/)

#### Converting Image to DATA URI

**A.) Canvas**

Load the image into an Image-Object, paint it to a canvas and convert the canvas back to a dataURL.

```
function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

***Usage***

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas('http://bit.ly/18g0VNp', function(base64Img){
    // Base64DataURL
});
```

***Supported input formats***
`image/png`, `image/jpeg`, `image/jpg`, `image/gif`, `image/bmp`, `image/tiff`, `image/x-icon`, `image/svg+xml`, `image/webp`, `image/xxx`

**B.) FileReader**

Load the image as blob via XMLHttpRequest and use the FileReader API to convert it to a data URL.

```
function convertFileToBase64viaFileReader(url, callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader  = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function () {
          callback(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

This approach

- lacks in browser support
- has better compression
- works for other file types as well.

***Usage***

```
convertFileToBase64viaFileReader('http://bit.ly/18g0VNp', function(base64Img){
    // Base64DataURL
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/1496715)

Comment: awesome thanks so much man, just one question though.  if I were uploading a lot of images, but the user would only be seeing a couple at a time, would base 64 be the best option for me? it seems to be simpler than the alternative.

Comment: can you go a little further in depth with your first option?  perhaps provide an example json object, that would be great!

Comment: *"base64 encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger"* but [gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16692852/1697459) is your friend when using solution 2.

Comment: I have some images stored in this format. Any idea how to convert them? [
{
"id": 1,
"format_id": 1,
"body": "|147,71,142,69,116,67,113,66,109,66,106,65,103,65,99,64,96,64,92,63,89,63,86,63,83,63,81,63,79,63,77,63,75,63,74,63,72,63|107,61,105,63,105,66,105,68,104,72,104,76,103,81,103,87,103,94,103,101,103,108,103,115,103,122,103,129,103,135,103,141,104,147,105,152,106,156,107,160|170,69,170,73,170,76,170,80,170,85,170,89,169,94,169,98,169,104,169,109,169,115,169,122,169,129,169,134,169,140,169,145,169,"}]

Answer (score 47):

The [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format can contain only those types of value:

- string
- number
- object
- array
- *true*
- *false*
- *null*

An image is of the type "binary" which is none of those.
So you can't *directly* insert an image into JSON. What you can do is convert the image to a textual representation which can then be used as a normal string.

The most common way to achieve that is with what's called [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Basically, instead of encoding it as `1` and `0`s, it uses a range of 64 characters which makes the textual representation of it more compact. So for example the number '64' in binary is represented as `1000000`, while in base64 it's simply one character: `=`.

There are many ways to encode your image in base64 depending on if you want to do it [in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) or not.

Note that if you're developing a web application, it will be way more efficient to store images separately in binary form, and store paths to those images in your JSON or elsewhere. That also allows your client's browser to cache the images.

Comment: thanks, I didnt really even know where to start because images didnt fall under those categories but now I understand.

Comment: the number 64 isn't just one character, it is:
NjQ=
the special char "=" means padding

Answer (score 11):

Use data URL scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

In this case you use that string directly in html : `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....">`

Answer (score 1):

To upload files directly to Mongo DB you can make use of Grid FS. Although I will suggest you to upload the file anywhere in file system and put the image's url in the JSON object for every entry and then when you call the data for specific object you can call for the image using URL.

Tell me which backend technology are you using? I can give more suggestions based on that.

Comment: I am using a java script framework called meteor which comes with all the back end technology installed already.  It includes mongo db so your suggestion could probably work.  Ill check it out thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/********** File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "Quotes.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"
            + uploadFileName + "'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.1.1.11/hhhh/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath + ""
                + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        + uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
            // + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + " http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                + uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText
                            .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

***PHP File***

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./Upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).    " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Comment: i am not really sure whats going on in your code... could you explain please

Comment: Basically putting the image in JSON using PHP, and Java @Dyll Bro

Comment: ok I see, could this code work universally? as in could I copy and paste this and get mine to work the same way