# Upload image to server in swift3

Tags: json, swift, image-uploading

I want to send an image as a parameter along with my request. I have used the code below to call my PUT request but I don't know how to append an image to the body.

```
  func myImageUploadRequest()
    {
        let headers = [
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]
        let parameters = [
            [
                "name": "Name",
                "value": "Swift"
            ],
            [
                "name": "Key",
                "fileName": "123.png"
//UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!)

            ]
        ]

        let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"

        var body = ""
        var error: NSError? = nil
        do{
        for param in parameters {
            let paramName = param["name"]!
            body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
            body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
            if let filename = param["fileName"] {
                let contentType = param["content-type"]!
                let fileContent = try String(contentsOfFile: filename as! String, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                }
                body += "; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n"
                body += "Content-Type: \(contentType)\r\n\r\n"
                body += fileContent
            } else if let paramValue = param["value"] {
                body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)"
            }
        }
       // }//do


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://——----docUpload/MediaUpload/")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
      //  request.httpBody = postData as Data
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }

        catch {
        } //new

}
```

I have seen many examples and tried but unable to implement it myself. please check my code and help me in this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PUT method.
try with POST method

Comment: only PUT method

Comment: I think your file attachment code is Ok, check with your server side,
because i was also spent one week but problem was at server side

Answer (score 0):

One option is to encode the image in Base64, which you can then include as a string in your json.  Although this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object) refers to javascript, it explains the pluses and minuses of this approach in general.

For syntax check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string), which lays out all possible options you might need, but the code below should provide you with the file content that you can add to the body of your request.

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere"), 
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {

    let fileContent = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
}
```