# Serve image/file in json

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

assume that I have class like this

```
public class Entity {
    private String name;
    private File file;

    // Getters & setters
}
```

is it possible to return object of this class as json? I'm using jax-rs

Comment: This question is already answered on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object/34485762

Comment: To be honest, I didn't found answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you're using JAX-RS, then I expect you to know the basic of creating a REST-ful Web Services ya.

You can use `@Produces("application/json")` annotation in one of your endpoint. Use that endpoint to return an Entity, and it will be automatically converted as JSON.