# serving images with graphql

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I have **graphql** server built by **express-graphql** and I use mongoDb to store images in normal database collection since they are < 16MB.

I have **react** and **android** app. What is the best way to serve these images to the clients.

In my schema I have something like this.

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
views: {type: Number, default: 0},
//Storing only thumbnail in this document.
thumbnail: {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
```

});
And in my schema I have something like

```
const productType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Product',
    fields: () => ({
        //.........
        thumbnail: {type: 'WHAT TO DO HERE'},
        views: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)}
        //.........
    }),
});
```

Edit:
I created a router like this.

```
router.get('/t/:productId', function (req, res) {
    const productId = req.params.productId;

    Product.findById(productId, {thumbnail: true}).then(thumbnail => {
        res.contentType(thumbnail.contentType);
        res.end(thumbnail.data, "binary");
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
        res.sendStatus(404);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL.js responses are serialized as JSON, which means you can't *serve* images with it. You can return either a URL or a Base64-encoded string representing the image, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485762/6024220). Either way the type for your field would be `GraphQLString`.

Comment: Thanks for you response! So which one is better between URL and Base64?

Comment: The former will require you to still figure out a way to actually serve the pictures from the server, while the latter will require you to convert the encoded strings into a usable format client-side. Which one is *better* depends on a lot of variables.

Comment: I created a separate router. Can you take a look if I have done it correctly. I edited above code