# Sending MultiPartFile as JSON request Property to Spring Boot REST COntroller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a JSON request like below and i want to attach my file i-e (pdf,jpeg,png,etc)  as part of JSON Request Body Like below.
How would i do that in spring boot REST API.?
My request Body is :

```
    {
   "data":{
      "caseCategoryPrefix":"PF",
      "caseNumber":"last name",
      "caseStatusId":1,
      "caseCategoryId":1,
      "caseAttachments":[
         {
            "caseAttachmentId":1,
            "attachmentTypeId":1,
            "createdBy":"abc",
            "file":"" // here i want to attach my file 
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: any best practice to achieve this would be highly appreciated , thanks

Comment: Check this out??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object/34485762

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now normal practice to upload file is first upload it, return ID and then save data object.

### Example 1:

To have 2 endpoints in controller. One for file upload, second one for data object save. **This method best for bigger files.**

```java
@PostMapping(
        value = "/file",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
)
public String uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    // upload file and return generated id;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/data")
public void saveData(@RequestBody Data data) {
    // save data you described. Instead of "file:" save "fileId:"
}
```

---

### Example 2:

To have 1 endpoint and insert file in data object as byte array. **This works only with small files.** Because byte array have some length limitation as far as I know.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/data")
public void saveData(@RequestBody Data data) {
    // save data you described with byte[] array in data object
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,Dumbo, the solution is valid but i have a different scenario where i have to relate attachment to its unique id and its type in database. like when i save json object in database i need to save "caseAttachments" object which is having attachment information along with its url where it is saved .

Comment: hi @TariqAbbas Did u get a solution for this?