# I want to return a class with with image property in asp.net core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return a class with with image property in asp.net core web api and i am using swager to test actions .
The class that i am using :

```
 public class UserIndexDTO
{
    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Unless you resort to ugly Base64 hacks, you can't really include binary data in JSON. Instead consider returning a URI to a controller-action that returns the binary contents. Another option is a `multipart/mixed` response - assuming your clients can handle that.

Comment: You can store the path to the file instead of the bytes.  Seems more efficient.  If you allow user uploads be sure to write your own filename/extension.  (case/switch for writing specific file extensions)  For security don't rely on user-inputted filenames.

Comment: Related: [How do you put an image file in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34485420/113116)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you could convert the image byte to base64 string, then you could return the base64 string to the clinet as the image body.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {


        Byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.png");   // You can use your own method over here.         
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(b, 0, b.Length);
        var result = new TestImage();
        result.ImageBase = base64String;
        result.ID = 1;



        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

Result:

[image]