# How to display local images from local json file in vue?

Tags: vue.js

So I have a json file with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "img": "pic1.jpg"
  }
]
```

I am making a vue project where after I import it I'm trying to use as the img name in src for my image:

```
  <div v-for="item in countries" :key="item.id">
              <img :src="../src/assets/images/`item.img`" alt="">
            </div>
```

But image doesn't appear, rest of the data is fine. How do I get the image?

Home.vue script

```
 <script>
   
    
    import { useDark, useToggle } from '@vueuse/core'
    import jsonData from "../data/country.json"
    export default {
      name: "Home",
      setup() {
        const isDark = useDark();
        const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);
        console.log(isDark.value);
        return {
          isDark,
          toggleDark
        }
      },
      data: function () {
        return {
          isSideOpen: false,
          drawer: true,
          isTheme: false,
          listView: false,
          show: false,
    
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          countries: jsonData
        }
      },
    }
    
    </script>
```

Vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [ 'resources/js/app.js'], //worls best without css
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: should it be `:src="\`../src/assets/images/${item.img}\`"`

Comment: Hi I tried this, not loading the image unfortunately :(

Comment: Check that your path is correct

Comment: yes it is, works fine normally but not if I try to access it with json

Comment: Does `<img src="../src/assets/images/pic1.jpg" alt="" />` work?

Comment: And are you using Vite or WebPack?

Comment: @BernardBorg I'm using vite and yes that works but still can't find a way to access stuff from json file for local images

Comment: What is `countries`?

Comment: Send more code and your `vite.config.js` file

Comment: @BernardBorg I've attached my component script and vite.config.js files. Countries is the name of the array where I'm storing data. Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Please check out this Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object I think we can't directly use static img in json file we sholud convert it to (base64) string file and then use it